# render a html table from DB and then store its content again

Tags: php, html, mysql, e-commerce, cart

I already know how to render rows into a table; I've been doing it like this:

```
<?php $render = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Clientes WHERE (tipocliente='1' AND estado!='M') ORDER BY apellido_part DESC") or die(mysqli_error($con)); ?>
   <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($render)):; ?>
      <tr>
          <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row1['idClientes']; ?></td>
```

But now, what if I want to store back to the DB the whole table? How do I do it? What I'm trying to do is render an HTML table with all the items from the DB. Then as some sort of cart, select how much of the items have to be associated with that Order, then press a buton and copy the values into the Items_order database. I don't know how to handle the rendered rows and then store them.

Comment: You mean you want to store the HTML rendering of this page in your DB? `file_get_contents` this page and then you should get the HTML, then just insert it..

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know its not a tutorial site, but maybe, just maybe you could  say "oh that thing you want to do is called *****, search it" instead of down voting, and assuming I already know what I'm looking for, which I'm not, that's why I'm asking for any kind of help...

Comment: @chris85 Thanks for answering but no, that isnt what I'm looking for, Im filling a html table with php, once the dynamic table is filled I want to re-store the dynamic table content to the DB again, if you have any idea of how i can do it I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the table content again into the DB, just set the $id of rendered objects as the name in a form field, then get the data back into the DB by clicking a submit button, and catch all the form fields names with a $_post event.